# Find the first record which caused SUM to become 0

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using MySQL 5.5 to store a table like:

```
sequence  category  value
1         A         100
2         A         200
3         A        -300  # sum becomes 0
4         B         200
5         B         500
```

For each category, I would like to find the first record (ordered by sequence) which caused `sum(value)` of the category to drop below 0.

My current solution is (SQL function pseudo code):

```
create function find_low_value(in_category) returns int
begin
  declare cursor select sequence, value from table where category = in_category;
  declare sum int default 0;

  open and fetch cursor;
  set sum = sum + value;
  if sum <= 0 then
    return sequence;
  end if;
end
```

But it is not efficient. Is there a better/ simpler solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this counts as "better/ simpler", but you can write it as a regular SQL query:

```
SELECT MIN(sequence)
  FROM ( SELECT t1.sequence
           FROM table_name t1
           JOIN table_name t2
             ON t2.category = t1.category
            AND t2.sequence <= t1.sequence
          WHERE t1.category = ...
          GROUP
             BY t1.sequence
         HAVING SUM(t2.value) <= 0
       )
;
```

Comment: wow, that's a powerful query, but i guess no one knows what it does without a code comment..

Answer (score 0):

select min(id),category,sum(value) as total_sum from test  group by category
having total_sum<=0